# Move .mozilla folder from home directory

Tags: firefox

I've managed to move my firefox profile in `about:profiles`, but `.mozilla` folder in the home directory still annoys me.

As far as I concerned, there is no way to do so in `about:config` since it affects profiles only. I've also been looking at `/usr/lib/firefox`, but have not succeed.

Comment: Alternatively, you can move that folder to another location and create a directory symbolic link pointing to previous actual path.

Comment: @Biswapriyo yes, but I'm trying to minimize amount of files in home directory in general.

Comment: If the Firefox profile is moved to another non-default path then `.mozilla` folder is not so important. Firefox has `-profile` command line option which can be used to open that new profile, `~/.mozilla/profiles.ini` just contains list of profiles.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, I deleted `.mozilla` folder and ran firefox as you said, it did start with wanted profile, but it created the folder (only without `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` in it). It also took more time for window to appear (about 2 seconds).